# Putting a word inside a math expression such that it's always typeset in roman

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Often I want to define a math symbol with a subscript or a superscript that is a word. Typically I use `\text` for this purpose, e.g. `X_\text{word}`, because (as I understand it) `\text` will use text spacing whereas `\mathrm` will typeset it as if it was w times o times r times d, and that might lead to different spacing.

However, I've noticed that in italic text (such as in theorem environment) `\text` will typeset "word" in italic, not roman. I don't think that's what I want it to do, because although 'word' is a word, in this case it's part of a math symbol, and I don't think the symbol should look different in a theorem environment from normal text.

Surprisingly, `\textrm` behaves the same as `\text`, setting the word in italic when used in a theorem environment. (This is true regardless of whether `amsmath` is loaded, but if `amsmath` is not loaded then it will also be the wrong size.)

So then the question is, what's the right command for this use case?

In the MWE below, the `\mathrm` version looks identical to the `\text` version in normal text - it doesn't have the weird spacing between letters that I was expecting. (I tried a few other words besides "word" but didn't find one where it looked different.) So part of this question is, am I just wrong about the behaviour of `\mathrm` - can I rely on it producing correct spacing for a word? If not, is there a command that does produce the correct spacing for a word, but always typesets it in roman?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\xwordi}{{X_\text{word}}}
\newcommand{\xwordii}{{X_\textrm{word}}}
\newcommand{\xwordiii}{{X_\mathrm{word}}}
\newcommand{\xwordiv}{{X_{\operatorname{word}}}}

\begin{document}

Here is $\xwordi$ (i) in a text environment. And in a superscript: $e^\xwordi$.

\begin{theorem}
    Here is $\xwordi$ (i) in a theorem environment. 
\end{theorem}

Here is $\xwordii$ (ii) in a text environment. And in a superscript: $e^\xwordii$.

\begin{theorem}
    Here is $\xwordii$ (ii) in a theorem environment.
\end{theorem}

Here is $\xwordiii$ (iii) in a text environment. And in a superscript: $e^\xwordiii$.

\begin{theorem}
    Here is $\xwordiii$ (iii) in a theorem environment.
\end{theorem}

Here is $\xwordiv$ (iv) in a text environment. And in a superscript: $e^\xwordiv$.

\begin{theorem}
    Here is $\xwordiv$ (iv) in a theorem environment.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Give `\textnormal{…}` or `\textup{…}` a try. (I’m pretty sure this is a dupe.)

Comment: @Mico thanks, both seem to work. I'd be surprised if someone hasn't asked this before, but I did search for duplicates before asking and wasn't able to find one.

Comment: This one is fairly close to a duplicate. (I only found it when searching for "textnormal vs textup". https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98406/which-command-should-i-use-for-textual-subscripts-in-math-mode. Additionally this one has a nice answer by @Mico explaining the differences in behaviour between the various options. (Again found by searching for textnormal and textup.) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244657/how-to-display-upright-letters-in-math-mode-without-manually-creating-space. (In summary it looks like `\textnomal` is the best option.)

Answer (score 2):

If you literally mean, always in Roman, you probably want `\text{\rmfamily\upshape #1}` from `amsmath` (or more precisely, `amstext`).  You can use any text-mode commands inside `\text`, including selecting any font family you please.  If you use this in a math expression, and want spacing like the `log` or `cos` operators, use `\mathop{\text{\rmfamily\upshape #1}}\nolimits`.

For math symbols that should be typeset as individual letters and not as words, use `\mathrm`, or `\symup` if you are using `unicode-math`.

Note that the reason I don’t just use `\textnormal` is to inherit the font weight of the surrounding text.  This allows me to add `\boldmath\bfseries` to the formatting of my section headers, and get matching bold text and math.  If you use medium-weight math even in bold headers, you would prefer `\textnormal`.

You also don’t want to use only `\textrm`, as that would give you italics if you happen to use it in an italic block (such as a theorem statement from `amsthm`).